# Archive, compress, remove old archive file then remove source file if below set size

Tags: bash, linux, shell, ksh

I'm working on a script that will archive, compress, clear old archive files, then remove the source file if it is below a set size.  The output when I tested it worked, but I just wanted a second look to make sure I'm not missing any issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# Script Name: archiving.ksh
# Purpose    : To copy and  Archive the files
#              $1 = Source file name pattern with fully qualified path
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#set -xv

sourcedir=$1
filename_pattern=$2
arcdir=/busdata/data/archive
filename=`ls $sourcedir/$filename_pattern*`
file_basename=`basename $filename`

echo $sourcedir
echo $arcdir
echo $filename_pattern
echo $filename
echo $file_basename

echo "Copying $filename to ${arcdir}"
cp $filename ${arcdir}/${file_basename}_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
compress ${arcdir}/$file_basename*

echo "Removing files that are more than 30 days old from ${arcdir}"
find ${arcdir} -mtime +15 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;

echo "Remove empty file"
find ${sourcedir} . -name "858_file_*.exp" -type 'f' -size -160k -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Is this intended to be portable (POSIX) shell?  And have you run shellcheck on it?

Comment: I have not run a shellcheck on it. it seems when I copied it over the top don't make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the following changes to the script for clarity and ease of use by others:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# Script Name: archiving.ksh
# Purpose    : To copy and archive the specified files
#              $1 = Fully qualified source directory for the script to run from
#              $2 = Source file name pattern
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# set -xv

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Illegal number of parameters passed to the script!"
  exit 1
fi

sourcedir="$1"
filename_pattern="$2"
arcdir="/busdata/data/archive"
filename=`ls $sourcedir/$filename_pattern*`
file_basename=`basename $filename`

echo "$sourcedir"
echo "$arcdir"
echo "$filename_pattern"
echo "$filename"
echo "$file_basename"

echo "Copying $filename to ${arcdir}..."
cp "$filename" "${arcdir}/${file_basename}_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
compress "${arcdir}/$file_basename"*

echo "Removing files that are more than 30 days old from ${arcdir}..."
find "${arcdir}" -mtime +15 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;

echo "Removing empty files..."
find "${sourcedir}" . -name "858_file_*.exp" -type 'f' -size -160k -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The first change is enforcing the expected number of script parameters, so the code doesn't behave unexpectedly if fewer parameters are given. The syntax is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18568726/6456163) if you are unfamiliar.

The next step is quoting all shell variables wherever possible for type safety, it's considered a best practice when you aren't sure what values will be passed. More information about this can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701642/6456163).

Outside of these changes I don't see anything that throws up any red flags in your code, it looks like it will do what is expected from it and nothing more/less.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the header comment is inaccurate, as it mentions only one argument, but the script expects two.

As [Aaron says](/a/281252/75307), quote all expansions, since you don't want word splitting to be performed on any of them.  That's the majority of the shellcheck results:

```
281239.sh:11:10: note: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticks `...`. [SC2006]
281239.sh:11:14: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:11:25: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:12:15: note: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticks `...`. [SC2006]
281239.sh:12:25: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:14:6: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:16:6: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:17:6: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:18:6: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:21:4: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:21:24: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:21:41: warning: Quote this to prevent word splitting. [SC2046]
281239.sh:22:20: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
281239.sh:28:6: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
```

A lot of expansions use braces where not necessary - I find that to be visual clutter, but if you prefer it, at least be consistent and use them *everywhere*.

Avoid substituting the output of `ls` into variables - many versions of `ls` will transform filenames for human readability (e.g. showing control characters).  And if the pattern expands to multiple filenames, `file_basename` will end up being something that's not usable in the way we attempt here.

I think the program is much too chatty - consider providing an option to turn on debugging output, but make it quiet by default.

Consider what happens when commands fail.  Here we ignore errors from `cp`, which means that the `compress` is almost certain to fail - more worryingly, we'll end up removing files that are not backed up:

> ```
> echo "Copying $filename to ${arcdir}"
> cp $filename ${arcdir}/${file_basename}_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
> compress ${arcdir}/$file_basename*
> ```

We should exit the script if the copy step fails.  Either add `|| exit` to the `cp` command, or add `set -e` to the script (in the latter case, we might want to proceed if compression fails - then add `|| true` to suppress the exit.

Instead of compressing all files that begin with the basename, perhaps just compress the single file we copied.  We'll need to put the target filename in a variable rather than invoking `date` again, so we don't get a different name.

GNU `find` has a `-delete` predicate that's more efficient than spawning `rm` for every match.

It's surprising that the last command includes the working directory as well as `$sourcedir` - make sure that users know that!

---

## Modified code

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# Script Name: archiving.ksh
# Purpose    : To copy and  Archive the files
#-----------------------------------------------------------

# If VERBOSE is set in the environment, be chatty on stdout

set -u

die() {
    echo >& "$@"
    exit 1
}

[ $# = 2 ] || die "Usage: $0 sourcdir filename"

sourcedir=$1
arcdir=/busdata/data/archive
filename=$sourcedir/$2
archive_file=$arcdir/$(basename "$filename")_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

if [ "${VERBOSE+x}" ]
then
    echo "$sourcedir"
    echo "$arcdir"
    echo "$2"
    echo "$filename"
    echo "$archive_file"
fi

cp ${VERBOSE+-v} "$filename" "$archive_file" || exit
compress ${VERBOSE+-v} "$archive_file"

${VERBOSE+echo "Removing files that are more than 30 days old from ${arcdir}"}
find "$arcdir" -mtime +15 -type f ${VERBOSE+-print} -delete

${VERBOSE+echo "Removing empty files from $sourcedir and $PWD"}
find "$sourcedir" . -name '858_file_*.exp' -type f -size -160k ${VERBOSE+-print} -delete
```